# NativeScript: Binding SearchBar submit event with view-model function/method?

Tags: typescript, nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

Hi I am having trouble binding NativeScript Searchbar submit event with a method I have declared inside the vew-model.ts.

```
`<SearchBar id="searchBar" hint="Search" text=""  clear="onClear" submit="{{ onSubmit }}"/>`

And the function in viewmodel:

`public onSubmit(args) {
        console.log('pressed');
        let searchBar = <SearchBar>args.object;
        var searchPhrase = searchBar.text;
        this.url = this.url+this.searchPhrase;
        this.getItems(this.url);
        console.log(this.url);
    }`
```

But this doesn't seem to be working. If I define the same method inside the code-behind file (main-page.ts) it's called no matter if I write it as:

```
`<SearchBar id="searchBar" hint="Search" text=""  clear="onClear" submit=" onSubmit"/>`
```

OR

```
`<SearchBar id="searchBar" hint="Search" text=""  clear="onClear" submit="{{ onSubmit }}"/>`
```

I am new to NativeScript and I don't know if I am missing anything. I did check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41163750/binding-itemtap-on-viewmodel-mathod-in-nativescript) answer and it didn't help because that was for TextFields. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onSubmit` should be a property of `ViewModel` in order to do event binding. Update the method as below.

```
onSubmit = (args) => {
    console.log('pressed');
    let searchBar = <SearchBar>args.object;
    var searchPhrase = searchBar.text;
    this.url = this.url+this.searchPhrase;
    this.getItems(this.url);
    console.log(this.url);
};
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but it's not working.. I am getting errors.
TS1054: A 'get' accessor cannot have parameters.
TS2378: A 'get' accessor must return a value.